# jquery each not iterating over object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently doing the following. I am lost as to why this simple function is not working. I am building an object dynamically and then I want to iterate over it. I have checked and the object does have content in it.

```
newChecked =[];

$.each(checked, function(index, value) {
newChecked[value.app]=value.admin;
});

$.each(newChecked, function(index, value) {
    //do some stuff here while iterating
});
```

I have put debugging lines inside the second `.each` and they are not being returned. it is completely ignoring the second `.each`

Comment: What is the content of `value.app`

Comment: Try placing this line in the first loop to debug: `console.log('loop1 with '+value.app+' and '+value.admin);`.

Comment: What is `value.app`, if it's a non-numeric string you should use an object map rather than an array.

Comment: Probably use `newChecked={};` instead of `newChecked=[];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are misunderstanding the use of an array. If you want an associative array/map, use a plain object instead of an array.

```
var newChecked = {};

$.each(checked, function(index, value) {
    newChecked[value.app] = value.admin;
});

$.each(newChecked, function (k, v) {
    console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: `value.app` could be number. Also, you can just take the second parameter from the callback to $.each, which will be the value. Not sure why you were downvoted, though.

Comment: @ColinDeClue , even if `value.app` is a number it will automatically be converted to a string when using it as an object key. Also, it's still better to use a plain object rather than an array if indexes aren't sequential. However you have a point with the value being passed to the callback, I will correct this.

Comment: the issue was that `value.app` is a string. I should have caught this, thanks for the refresher.

Answer (score 0):

you have defined newChecked an array, thus please ensure that value.app is of type number

> eg: if checked = checked = [{app : 0, "admin" : "cba"}, {app : 1, "admin" : "fed"}]
>
> than newChecked will be : ["cba", "fed"]
>
> Whereas if checked = [{app : 0, "admin" : "cba"}, {app : 2, "admin" : "fed"}],
>
> then undefined will be added to the index 2 of array newChecked :
>
> ["cba", undefined, "fed"]